# How to capture Query Status(Sleeping, Background, Running) in SQL Server Profile trace

Tags: sql-server-2012

Is there any EventClass/Data Column which can log the Query Status to trace in SQL Server Profiler?

Query Status which we find through sys.dm_exec_requests

Comment: Whats the point in capturing through profiler / what are you trying to achieve ? You can dump the data of DMV into a table - which will be much light weight as compared to running profiler to capture query status.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It is just a question I had whether we can capture the query status while running the profiler. Not looking for anything specific!!!

Answer (score 1):

Profiler does not capture point in time information (ie, what is the status of this query or wait times/types or current blocks, however you can get deadlock events). But rather, it captures activity/event information (ie, this activity/event occurred so record it). As such, it will not be able to give you that kind of information since it is always runnable when those activities are occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adam Machanic's sp_WhoIsActive procedure.
www.sqlblog.com
There is an option to save the results to a table.
Brent Ozar has an article about how to do it here:
https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/
It is not a "trace" but will give you the information.